# VBA Excel - if statement doesn't work as intended

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My problem is that the statement in 'if' returns false even tho values are 14271 and 5, what could be reason for that?

textbox5 returns "wybierz inna sumeFalse 5 14271" in else

```
Sub Wyplac_2()
 Dim sh1 As Worksheet
 Dim sh2 As Worksheet
 Dim sh3 As Worksheet
 Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("konta")
 Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Interfejs")
 Set sh3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("stale")
 y = TextBox5.Text
 z = ((sh1.Range("G" & (sh3.Range("K3") + 2))) > y)
 x = ((sh1.Range("G" & (sh3.Range("K3") + 2))))

 If (x > y) Then
  TextBox5.Text = y
  sh1.Range("G" & sh3.Range("K3") + 2) = sh1.Range("G" & sh3.Range("K3") + 2) - y
  TextBox4.Text = "Prosze wziasc pieniadze"
  CommandButtonGrab.Visible = True
  CommandButton11.Visible = False
  sh3.Range("K4") = 11
  GoTo gohere
 Else
  TextBox4.Text = "Brak srodkow na koncie"
  TextBox5.Text = "Wybierz inna sume" & z & " " & y & " " & x
 End If

 gohere:
End Sub
```

Comment: Translating the strings to English will make your question clearer to possible answerer.

Comment: Besides translating your strings, please also make sure to post a minimum example where issue can be replicated.

Answer (score 0):

Y is defined as text, X is numeric. Even if Y is a number it's still being treated as text, not a numeric value.   Convert Y to a numeric value before the IF statement.